# What are the "bytes touched" in V8 Parse processor?

Tags: javascript, compilation, v8

I recently started to play around with [V8 parse processor](https://v8.github.io/tools/head/parse-processor.html), and found there was something called bytes touched along the graph. what does it mean?

And when i tried to apply the IIFE heuristics to eager parse my function, i found that the pre-parse time was reduced. What happens in the pre-parse time? Also, what are the these terminologies such as baseline time, resolution time and nesting level mean?

Even though I executed the function, it still shows up as "non-executed" in parse time. Why is it so?

[image: Parse processor graph]

Answer (score 1):

> What are the "bytes touched" in V8 Parse processor?

The number of bytes seen/processed by the parser or preparser. (I don't know why it would ever be negative, that seems surprising; but maybe there's a good reason for it.)

> What happens in the pre-parse time?

Preparsing is the initial quick pass over code that will be lazy-compiled later. It's required in order to:

- find out which functions exist, and where in the source they are
- find out which variables from their outer scopes they refer to, so that these variables can be context-allocated
- throw "early errors" as required by the JS spec
- and maybe a few other things that I'm not thinking of right now.

For functions that will be eagerly compiled immediately, preparsing can be skipped. Usually it's beneficial to preparse and lazy-compile though (so any future readers of this: please don't feel tempted to minimize preparsing time, that'd most likely be counter-productive!).

> what are the these terminologies such as baseline time, resolution time and nesting level mean?

"baseline time": time for baseline (non-optimized) compilation
"resolution time": time for variable resolution
"nesting level": when a function is defined inside another function, they're "nested". Obviously this can go many levels deep.

> Even though I executed the function, it still shows up as "non-executed" in parse time. Why is it so?

Because tracking executed functions in the Parse Profiler is [currently not implemented](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/bed5bc495f509bd962cd75bcf7ba8b0e52ac8c8a/test/cctest/test-log.cc#1143), apparently because nobody needed it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! But however when I run the parse profiler on some well known websites (like google.com), the executed section is indeed changing! But however it doesnt do the same in mine, even though i executed them in loops, etc.

Comment: EDIT: As you said, the function execution tracking is indeed not implemented in D8 compiler. When i run it from a webpage, it works!